# Update multiple rows in sql table for checkbox selections

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I would like to update my dbo.userDepartment table (a middle table that links to dbo.User and dbo.Department) base on the Department checkboxes that the user has selected.

On my backend page, I have two objects, Department and DepartmentCollection.

Department has DeptId, DeptName

DepartmentCollection is a list

On my frontend page, I display all the Department options for user to **select or deselect**.

When I click save on my Edit User Page, I would like to  update dbo.userDepartment.

My problem is, how can I do this so i can successfully update:

1. Department that user has originally selected but is now deselected.
2. Department that user has not selected before but is now selected.
3. Department that remains unselected.

How can I write my stored procedure to achieve what I want? 
I am thinking about passing in an array of deptid and compare the array with what is being stored in the database. delete a record or insert a record based on whether or not the id exists in the array i pass in.

This is what i can think of so far. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: In the userDepartment table do you store just the records UserID & DepartmentID selected by the user ?

Comment: In one transaction, Wipe out all existing records and replace them with ones based on the values from the page.

Comment: The problem here is really about deleting the row that belongs to the department that was originally selected but is now being deselected. Because if I only pass in the ids of all the selected depts, i wouldn't know which one to delete.

Comment: Steve: yes, i only store the selected depts belong to a userId.

Comment: T.S.: Yea...that sounds like an approach. But wouldn't it be a waste of resources to update the records if the user belongs to 10 depts, and now everything remain unchanged except one more dept is being selected. I am recreating 10 records which were already there in the first place.

Comment: That's the reason I have asked if you store just the userID and the departmentID. It is a lot simpler and probably faster to clear the previous selection using the UserID as the key and then reinserting everything than checking every single data to decide if you need a delete or an insert

Comment: @user2280133: Any other approach will lead to need to create some sort of code locking, etc. You need not to worry about "waste of resources". This is metadata - this is small. It should be atomic, not breakable, single piece of logic. Think about this, is this operation that is done by users all day long?  - if the answer is "No", you don't need to worry about. Waste of resources happening when you have 10,000 transactions. Users/departments - this is nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing the your user has ID=1 and belonged to 5 departments with ID = 1..5. 
After the page update the user belongs to department 3..7.

The simplest way to do your update (in pseudocode)

```
 Start A Transaction
 DELETE FROM userDepartment WHERE UserID=1
 for each department choosen
    INSERT INTO userDepartment (userID, deparmentID) values (1, departmentIDChoosen)
 Next
 Commit Transaction
```

I don't think that it is a significant and noticeable depletion of resources. We are talking about 10/20 records right? The best approach would be passing a [Table Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to a stored procedure so to call the database just one time

In your database create the TYPE for the TVP parameter and the storedprocedure

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.UserDeptTableType AS TABLE
    ( UserID int, DeptID int )

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UpdateUserDepartment
(@userID int, @tbpNewDepts dbo.UserDeptTableType READONLY)
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
    DELETE FROM userDepartment WHERE UserID=@userID
    INSERT INTO dbo.userDepartment (UserID, DeptID)
    SELECT ud.UserID, ud.DeptID FROM @tvpNewDepts AS ud
COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
```

in your C# code create the table with the userID and DeptID and pass it to the stored procedure

```
using (connection)
{
      DataTable depts = GetUserIDWithDepartments();
      SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_UpdateUserDepartment", connection);
      insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", currentUserID);
      SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpNewDepts", depts);
      tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
      insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: see my last comment above. Is there a more resource efficient way?

Comment: Okay. I guess you are right. It might not be as expensive as I thought. One more question, how to I handle the @tvpNewDepts parameters? Should my depts be a String of ids like "1, 2, 3" or should i pass in an array of integer? Sorry, I am a newbie and is not very familiar with the tale type. Can you elaborate more on this? Thank you.

Comment: No, I haven't detailed the `GetUserIDWithDepartments()` This should create a DataTable, add two integer columns with the required names and then, looping on your selected checkboxes add a row composed of the userid and deptid. The DataTable is passed as is to the stored procedure. Just one call to the database (and this is the most resource intensive task involved here)

Comment: A simple example on how to create a DataTable and add rows to it http://www.dotnetobject.com/Thread-Generate-dynamic-DataTable-c

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether there's enough to go on here. Are the three states listed above to be represented differently within the userDepartment table?

If so, then the stored procedure alone will not be able to achieve this without being given some help by the UI, which of course need the original state of the selection from the database.

On point 1 - would a user selecting and then deselecting a checkbox before postback fall into this category, or would that be 3?

When you say 'not selected before' in point 2 - is that 'not ever selected before', or just wasn't selected when the page was rendered this time round, but may have been selected and later deselected at some point in the past?

If some or all of these are true, then you'll need to define all possible states of the checkbox, so that when the page is saved, then given the checkbox's previous state, and the action (either check or uncheck) that has occurred on the page, you know what state it needs to be transitioned to.

Comment: No. My dbo.UserDepartments only has two columns. UserId and DeptId.

Comment: In that case, the answer above is on the right lines. Presumably the table's indexed by UserId, so just clear out that user's rows and reinsert the latest selection.